# Ios crash when trying to do playerPhysicsBody.node?.addChild(emitter!)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

for some reason, whenever i win the game, that is the player hits the target, the app crashes at line
 playerPhysicsBody.node?.addChild(emitter!)
with an error 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
any help here please?

Comment: you're assuming emitter is not nil, you should first check whether emitter exists. use "guard let" on the emitter instance

Comment: can u please show me how to do that.. i am not sure i have used guard let. thanks :)

Comment: Read the linked duplicate. It explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

Before Execute Check Whether Is Null Or Not.

```
    if(playerPhysicsBody != nil){
          playerPhysicsBody.node?.addChild(emitter!)
    }
```